# POST method to send strings to JsonArray

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

I am creating an app in which I have to send or Post data to the server. I am able to send data To object or array but I am not able to send data first in the object than in its subarray and then an object Can anyone help me out with this problem I will be very thankful. Data to be sent in the form given Below.

```
{
name:
no:
data: [
 {
    surname:
    option:
   another_option:
 }
]
another:
}
```

I want to POST my data in strings, as it is in object Form I want to update ArrayList in one of the objects but I am not able to get how to send data in My " data: " as I am not able to get how to post my string values in array list in my parameters. There can be n no. of array list in my objects of ArrayList. I am not able to get how to send or put my data in POST method please help me out

Here is my code I am trying.

```
 private void new_process() {

    String URL = "http://117.240.196.238:8080/api/raid";

    Log.i("response", URL);
    StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("response_process", response);
            Upload_work(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("volley", "Error" + error.getMessage());
                    Log.i("response_error", error.toString());

                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String lic_date, lic_letter, lic_copy, sale_date, sale_letterno, sale_copy, material_name, material_quantity, quantity_in, fir_num, fir_dates, fir_policestation, sample_code, sample_date;                                       List<String> number = new ArrayList<>();

            number.add(first_text);
            number.add(second_text);
            number.add(third_text);

            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("no.", number);
            params.put("data", ?????); // how to pass my list of string number to this data
            params.put("another", another);

            return params;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue queue = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
}

private void Upload_work(String response) {
    Log.i("response_Upload_work", response);
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        int success = json.getInt("success");
        String msg = json.getString("message");
        if (success == 1) {
            JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject("data");
            String messg = c.getString("message");
            Toast.makeText(this, messg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("responseNew m", "Exception : " + ex.toString());
    }

}
```

I have tried to create a JsonArray and then create a Jsonobject and then pass the json array in my parameters but i am not able to link both jsonArray With jsonobject

```
JsonArray sample_obj = new JsonArray();
                try {
                    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();

                    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(j.toString());

                    c.put("name", sample_code);
                    c.put("value", "google.com");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Please help me out if I am doing it in a correct way or what else I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for(**:**:**){
    JSONObject jsOb = new JSONObject();
    jsOb.put("surname", a);
    jsOb.put("option", b);
    jsOb.put("another_option", c);
    jsonArray.put(jsOb);
}

 jQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            String jurl = URL---------------------;

            final UserLocalStore userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(getApplicationContext());


            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
            try {

                jsonObject.put("name", x);
                jsonObject.put("no", y);

                jsonObject.put("data", jsonArray);
                jsonObject.put("another", z);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





            //Log.d("check param",jsonObject.toString());

            final JsonObjectRequest jrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(jurl, jsonObject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {



                            Log.d("Volley",response.toString());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.e("**VolleyError", "error" + error.getMessage());

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return super.getParams();
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {


                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    CurrentUser user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();


                    String credentials = user.getUsername()+":"+user.getPassword();
                    String auth = "Basic "
                            + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                    return headers;
                }
            };


            jQueue.add(jrequest);
        }
```

see above example

Comment: Updated my code Will this Work

JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(); try { json2.put("name", name); json2.put("no", number); } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } JsonArray sample_obj = new JsonArray(); sample_obj.add(String.valueOf(json2)); params.put("Raid_Sample", sample_obj.toString());

Comment: if i am able to solve my problem then why i am asking Questions. I just want to clear my doubts that if i want to send my data in Object first then send my data in Array and then in object as givien in the sample code in first Paragraph.

Comment: Can you explain your doubt I can't understand what you said?

Comment: sir i just want to post data to server Using volley but i am not able to get how to send data in the exact form i have showing in first coding part that is to send data in a object and then send data in array which has two objects

Comment: sir can uh help me out what if i have to send multiple objects in array list to server i am getting only one list data or one object data but i want to post all data to server or every object to server

Comment: Please paste your json to understand which type data you send to server.

Comment: Sir here is the question which have full details pls can uh help me out with your ans here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181245/recyclerview-list-to-server

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSONArray

> import org.json.JSONArray;

not JsonArray

> import com.google.gson.JsonArray;

```
        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray sample_obj = new JSONArray();
        try {
            json2.put("name", "name"); json2.put("no", "number");
            sample_obj.put(json2);
        } catch (JSONException e)
        { e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    json2.put("name", name);
                    json2.put("no", number);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JsonArray sample_obj = new JsonArray();
                sample_obj.add(String.valueOf(json2));
                
                params.put("Raid_Sample", sample_obj.toString());

Comment: sir what if i have to send multiple objects in array list its only sending my one data only what if i have to send multiple data/object