# Recyclerview list to server

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a Project in which i have 3 edit text and one button. On button Click it add my data to Recyclerview successfully and it's working fine.

Now i want to post the recyclerview data to server using volley Post method can any one help me out how can i do it i just need a idea how to send data of recyclerview(list of my Recyclerview) to server. I want to Post full list of objects in array to server.

what should i send to my parameters so that i Successful post the recyclerview data to my server.

// Recycler view adapter

```
public class MoviesAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter1.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie1> moviesList1;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre1);
        }
    }

    public MoviesAdapter1(List<Movie1> moviesList1) {
        this.moviesList1 = moviesList1;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie1 movie = moviesList1.get(position);
        holder.title.setText("Name : " +movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText("Address : " +movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText("Contact No. : " +movie.getYear());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList1.size();
    }
}
// movie class

public class Movie1 {
    private String title, genre, year;

    public Movie1(String title, String genre, String year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

// Main Activity

```
listview_text = findViewById(R.id.witness_text1);
        b1tv1 = findViewById(R.id.witness_text);
        listview_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                        Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
                        movie.getGenre();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                    }
                }));

                final AlertDialog.Builder ablerDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScrollingActivity.this);
                final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_expand, null);
                ablerDialogue.setView(customLayout);
                alertDialog = ablerDialogue.create();
                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                movie_name = (EditText) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
                movie_add = (EditText) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_address);
                movie_no = (EditText) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_number);
                member_close = (ImageView) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.close_image);
                member_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                        listview_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });

                list_button = (Button) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_add_button);
                list_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        itemName = witness_name.getText().toString();
                        post = witness_add.getText().toString();
                        designation = witness_no.getText().toString();
                        if (witness_name() == true) {
                            witness_submit();
                            listview_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            b1tv1.setText("Witness details");
                        }

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        });
```

// Connection With Server

```
private void new_process() {

  String URL = "My URL";

    Log.i("response", URL);
    final StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("response_process", response);
            Upload_work(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("volley", "Error" + error.getMessage());
                    Log.i("response_error", error.toString());

                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();




            params.put("sending to", movieList1.toString());

            return params;
        }


    };
    RequestQueue queue = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
}

private void Upload_work(String response) {
    Log.i("response_Upload_work", response);
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        int success = json.getInt("success");
        String msg = json.getString("message");
        if (success == 1) {
            JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject("data");
            String messg = c.getString("message");
            Toast.makeText(this, messg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("responseNew m", "Exception : " + ex.toString());
    }

}
```

i want to post my recycler view data list to server in form

```
[
{movie_name : 
    movie_Add :
    movie_no:
    }
{movie_name : 
    movie_Add :
    movie_no:
    }
{movie_name : 
    movie_Add :
    movie_no:
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 JSONArray movieArray = new JSONArray();

 for(int i=0; i<=movieList.size(); i++) {
 JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject();
 try {
    movieObject.put("movie_name", ""+movieList.get(i).movieName);
    movieObject.put("movies_Add", ""+movieList.get(i).movieAdd);
    movieObject.put("movie_no", ""+movieList.get(i).movieNo);
    movieArray.put(movieObject);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }

JSONObject movieArrayObj = new JSONObject();
movieArrayObj.put("moviesInfo", movieArray);

String jsonStr = movieArrayObj.toString();
System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);
```

Comment: add some details as well supporting the answer

Comment: Got your answer but will it work if i have 5 time names and add and no. in my list which are added manually by the user then will it send only one data to server or it will send multiple objects data to server.

Comment: @sunny Updated my answer. check now

Comment: @sunny before sending your data to server I'm printing here System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr); the generated JSON format check that once for your satisfaction

Comment: [{"movie_name":"trtrtrtr","movies_Add":"trtrtrtr677676","movie_no":"9090909090"},{"movie_name":"trtrtrtr","movies_Add":"trtrtrtr677676","movie_no":"9090909090"}]
[{"movie_name":"oioi","movies_Add":"iooiio","movie_no":"6666666666"},{"movie_name":"oioi","movies_Add":"iooiio","movie_no":"6666666666"},{"movie_name":"oioi","movies_Add":"iooiio","movie_no":"6666666666"}

Comment: @ManiKandan Sir i am getting output like this its giving same object 3 time with same data.

Comment: @sunny you checked your list size

Comment: @ManiKandan sir i have checked its size is 1 on first click 2 on second click i changed the value of int i from 0 to 1 but and this problem solved but when i enter data 2nd time then it run 2 times and 2 object are created with same data and previous data is lost somewhere new array list show 2 data object with same data

Comment: jarraylist: [{"movie_name":"tuyyuit","movies_Add":"lbdjhlk","movie_no":"9879879877"}]
arraylistsize: 1
jarraylist: [{"movie_name":"tarrrr","movies_Add":"urtiuyiuy","movie_no":"0009090909"},{"movie_name":"tarrrr","movies_Add":"urtiuyiuy","movie_no":"0009090909"}]
arraylistsize: 2

Comment: can I see your code how you are adding your data to list

Comment: @ManiKandan sir i have used same code as uh have mentioned in your ans i have use this code on button click when all 3 edittext are filled and on click it save the edttext values to recyclerview list but its now showing only first value every time i enter new values to be added

Comment: are you sending data to server while adding data to recycler view each time

Comment: yes ,Actually first i am fetching data in objects if there are multiple there should be multiple objects all in a array and at last i am sending the final array list to server using volley

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207660/discussion-between-mani-kandan-and-sunny).

Comment: Mani Kandan sir can uh please help me out ?? i am still stucked at same position till now

Comment: @ManikandanKaruppiyah  sir here i am not able to solve a littel problem can uh help m eout ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790242/selected-item-id-in-spinner

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<String> movieList;  //you can define it to globally

 movieList=new ArrayList<>();
        movieList.add("1");
        movieList.add("2");
        movieList.add("3");


        JSONArray movieArray = new JSONArray();

        for(int i=0; i<movieList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                movieObject.put("movie_name", "" + movieList.get(i).toString());

                movieArray.put(movieObject);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.d("--------------------", String.valueOf(movieArray));
```

try this

output:

```
D/--------------------: [{"movie_name":"1"},{"movie_name":"2"},{"movie_name":"3"}]
```

Comment: getting error at movielist.add("1");

Cannot convert type of expression new Movie(itemName, post, designation) from com.example.raid.Recycler_list_work.Movie to java.lang.String   Cannot convert type of expression movie from com.example.raid.Recycler_list_work.Movie to java.lang.String

Comment: List<String> movieList; addx= this globally

Comment: i am not able to get you sir

Comment: add List<String> movieList; before movieList=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I am not able to add my data in place of ur "1" , "2","3"

Comment: Ak23 Can uh please explain ur ans?

Comment: can uh help me out  sir please?